# Angular cli conflicts while ng serve

Tags: angular

[image]

by mistake, I have to install angular 7 but the project I developed in angular 6, now I have to have this warning below, what can I do to bring back to angular 6 again, thank you

Comment: Can you please write the error/warning?

Comment: Your global Angular CLI version (7.3.5) is greater than your local
version (6.2.9). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am also facing the similar issue. But it is just a warning. It doesn't create any problem. You can continue to build or serve your angular project. It will run on angular 6, without any issue, as your local version is angular 6. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your project is using the local version of angular cli, which is great. you are just seeing this warning which can be suppressed by running this command.
`ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false`.

This is the right way, to have the latest version of angular cli installed globally and use specific versions for each project.

Answer (score 0):

You may upgrade your project (local version) to angular 7, or you can downgrade the global version to angular 6 are possible solutions. 
However, having the latest version of angular cli installed globally and using specified angular cli versions in your projects is perfectly normal.